# How do I reduce the horizontal space between my menu items [Home, About Us,...] is CSS?

Tags: html, css

I would like to manually reduce the horizontal space between my menu items so that I can be able to add other links without increasing the width of the menu bar.

Below is the image of my menu bar:

[image]

And here is my CSS code:

```css
#menu li{
 
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 150px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 font-family: Tahoma,san-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0px;
 
}
```

Comment: Reduce the width of the items, or try changing padding for the li

Comment: reduce the width of list-item

Comment: add #menu li{ margin-left: -10px }

Comment: Okay, let me try that

Comment: @fcalderan  Thanks it worked, so the `width` there is for the size of each list element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rely on `line-height` and `padding` instead of `height` and `width`. Try this:

```
#menu li {
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Tahoma,san-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width` Or give auto from li and give `padding`. So, it will works well if your menu text have more character.

```
#menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: Tahoma,san-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mybufq8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Change width to auto, to get the width to be the size of the word

```
#menu li{
   width: auto;
}
```

or change the actual size of the width

```
 #menu li{
   width: 120px;
}
```

And then add padding `padding:0 5px;`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do away with width / dimensions for the `li`'s and use the anchor elements within them to style them (add padding, borders, etc)?

I assume you've got a layout similar to the below:

```css
ul#menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: red;
  }
ul#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
ul#menu li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">FAQ's</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Using the above format means you can control the margins between the outer `li`'s (`ul#menu li { margin-left: 5px; }` for example) easier, without fear of messing up the styling of the menu items / links themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the width of you `li`. sometimes people want a fixed width of `li` but good practice are use `padding`. Try to preview Snippet in full width.

```css
ul li{
 
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 width: 120px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 font-family: Tahoma,san-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0px;
    background: gray;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
 
}
ul li:last-child{
 
 
    border-right:0px;
 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About Us</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Technology</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
  <li>new</li>
  <li>new</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```css
#menu{ float:left; background:black; width:100%}

#menu li{
 text-decoration: none;
 float: left;
 display: block;
 max-width: 150px;
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 55px;
 font-family: Tahoma,san-serif;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0px;
 width:100%;
 background:red;
 border-right:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
 <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

This is also a method to resolve your problem.